# What is "data distribution"? Does it Belong to Probability Space?

Tags: probability, distributions, density-function

While reading the paper [BEGAN : Boundary Equilibrium Generative Adversarial Network](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.10717.pdf) the autor writes as following:

*"the generator $G(z)$, which maps a sample $z$ from uniform distirubiton to the data distribution, and the discriminator $D(x)$ which determines if a sample $x$ belongs to the data distribution"*

I think I understood what they are trying to do.. and see the reproduced codes and its corresponding result too.

But my question is pretty simple **"What is data distribution?"** More in detail, when we are talking about distribution, I consider it as a probability distribution. However, the problem is then does it mean every point of x which is all collected into a set to be a mathematical object has a predetermined probability which comprise a well-defined $PDF$ or it only comprise the $joint-PDF$ with given any well-known and well-defined distribution $z$, such as Normal or Uniform etc.

More formally,

1) Does PDF of $X$ exist?

2) or we have a $belief$ that JointPDF of $X\times Z$ exist?

Hard for me to get to the very basic start of data science before understand the underlying rationals.

Comment: Sounds like they are referring to the data generating process. Does this answer your question? *[A] notional and non-specific probabilistic model (not directly described or explicitly set down) that would include all of the random influences that combine together to lead to individual observations, where one instance would be the supposed justification of the "common occurrence" of the normal distribution in terms of a combination of multiple random additive effects.* - from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_generating_process

Comment: Some technical nitpicks that might be of importance: (1) the right mathematical object is not a set but rather a sequence or multiset (so that repeated values may be distinguished); (2) not all distributions have PDFs and in particular finite distributions, which necessarily are discrete, will be continuous nowhere and therefore do not have PDFs.  It's unclear what you mean by "$Z$" since the only time it appears is in your second question.

Comment: @whuber $Z$ means well-defined and already-know distributions with parameters. And for the use of PDF It would be better to change it as PDF or PMF

Comment: I cannot understand the role this vaguely-described $Z$ has in your question.  You ask three questions--one in the title and two more numbered ones at the end--and all three are different.  Please edit your post to make it clearer what you are trying to ask and to narrow it to one specific question.